# MS Access db error

Tags: database, ms-access, vba

Im getting a error 3061 too few parameters at this line

```
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
```

This is the full code

```
Dim strSQL As String
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset ''Requires reference to Microsoft DAO x.x Library
Set db = CurrentDb()
MsgBox Me.LName
MsgBox Me.EmpID
strSQL = "SELECT LastName AS damn FROM [Employees]" & _
                 "WHERE [Employees].EmployeeID = Me.EmpID"
Debug.Print strSQL
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
MsgBox rs!damn
Me.LName = rs!damn
MsgBox Me.LName
rs.Close
db.Close
```

Comment: Examine what `Debug.Print strSQL` shows you.  Please paste that text into your question if you still need help.

Comment: @HansUp as I remember (Dont have the db now) it printed the sql statement as it is without the AS damn part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best I can assume is that

```
"WHERE [Employees].EmployeeID = Me.EmpID"
```

should be

```
"WHERE [Employees].EmployeeID = " & Me.EmpID
```

Plus HansUp has given you a great way to troubleshoot this in the future.

Comment: Good start.  Viewing `Debug.Print strSQL` will also confirm that statement is missing a space or line break between the table name and `WHERE`.

Comment: Nice catch, didn't spot that one.  I appreciate that you went the "Teach a man to fish..." route of answering.

Comment: I tried the same SQL code except the strSQL = part and it worked as a query. Unfortunately its a work problem and wont be able to confirm now